# Is it possible to rename a button's name with jQuery to execute different php-scripts depending on the button's name?

Tags: php, jquery, button, rename

I got a script with a navigation list (monday to sunday) and i wanna change a button's name depending on which day has "active"-class. I know how to select the element with the active class (and how to change the class). To receive the active class' name I use the following code:

```
var day=$('#navi ul li a.active').html();
```

But I was not able to change the name of the submit button. I tried this:

```
$('#loadStandard').name = $('#loadStandard').name + "_" + day;
```

This didnt change anything. I also tried:

```
$('#loadStandard').name= "bla";
```

but it didnt work. According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_submit_name.asp) it's the correct syntax. My form looks like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo plugins_url('plugin_directory/my_plugin.php'); ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="loadStandard" class="loadStandard" id="loadStandard" value="Load standard values">
</form>
```

I want to change the name of the button so I can make different if statements in my php script. Kinda like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['loadStandard_monday'])) {
    do something;
}
elseif(isset($_POST['loadStandard_tuesday'])){
    do something else;
}
```

Is it even possible? What am I doing wrong? Please help me with some tips, links or code snippets!

Comment: There is $(selector).attr('attrname', new_value); function in jQuery. It will be `$('#loadStandard').attr('name', $('#loadStandard').attr('name') + "_" + day);` in your case

Comment: try $('#loadStandard').attr({'name':'yourname');

Comment: Yeah thx! $('#loadStandard').attr({ "name": "loadStandard_"+day }); worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments mention, you need to use `.attr('name', day)`.

Or may I suggest you just use a hidden value instead?

```
<input type="hidden" name="loadStandard[day]"  id="loadStandard_day" value="" />
```

---

```
$('#loadStandard_day').val(day);
```

---

```
<?php
if ($_POST['loadStandard']['day'] == '...')
    //...
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any advantage using a hidden value?

Comment: I think it's cleaner and more reliable than changing names on the fly, but generally not really. I just prefer to mess with values and not attributes that should stay static.

Comment: ah ok, thx. Guess then I'm using the not so clean on the fly method because I'm lazy and it's shorter and I can handle the chaos ;)

Comment: Whatever floats your boat in this case, there is no real best practice for that, just make sure you don't lazy out of things that do have best practices :)

Answer (score 1):

Strange approach. You can do it like this:

```
var day=$('#navi ul li a.active').html(),
    submit_name = $('#loadStandard').attr('name');
$('#loadStandard').attr('name', submit_name+ "_" + day);
```

It will be better if you will use some hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="day" id="id-day" value=""/>

var day=$('#navi ul li a.active').html();
    $('#id-day').val(day);
```

and on the server side:

```
switch($_POST['day']) {
   case "sunday":
      ...
      break;
   case "monday":
      ...
      break;
   ...
}
```